# Issues with applying different discounts in subclasses using inheritance in C#

Tags: c#

I have two classes, the `Customer` is the base class, and `ValuedCustomer` is the class which inherits from the base class. The `Customer` class has a discount of 0% (class variable) and the `ValuedCustomer` (class variable) has a discount of 10%.

The owes method uses the discount variable to determine the amount owed. How do I allow the Valued customer to use its own discount variable?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Customer
{
    public class Customer
    {
        private float discount = 0; //CV
        public string name;
        public float balance;
        public string addr1;
        public string addr2;
        public string addr3;

        public Customer(string name, float balance, string addr1, string addr2, string addr3)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.balance = balance;
            this.addr1 = addr1;
            this.addr2 = addr2;
            this.addr3 = addr3;
        }

        public virtual float owes()
        {
            return Math.Abs(balance * discount - balance);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0}\n{1:0.00}\n{2}\n{3}\nBalance: {4}\nDiscount: {5}%\nAmount due: {6:0.00}", name,addr1,addr2,addr3,balance,discount*100, owes());
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer c1 = new Customer("Jimmy", 100, "22 Main Street", "Naas", "Kildare");
            ValuedCustomer c2 = new ValuedCustomer("Lucy", 100, "23 Main Street", "Roosky", "Roscommon");
            Customer c3 = new Customer("Fred", 200, "24 Main Street", "Sneem", "Kerry");

            Console.WriteLine(c1);
            Console.WriteLine(c2);
            Console.WriteLine(c3);
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Customer
{
    public class ValuedCustomer : Customer
    {
        private float discount = 0.1f;

        public ValuedCustomer(string name, float balance, string addr1, string addr2, string addr3) : base(name,balance,addr1,addr2,addr3)
        {
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0}\n{1:0.00}\n{2}\n{3}\nBalance: {4}\nDiscount: {5}%\nAmount due: {6:0.00}", name, addr1, addr2, addr3, balance, discount * 100, owes());
        }
    }
}
```

Expected example output:

```
Jimmy
22 Main Street
Naas
Kildare
Balance: 100
Discount: 0%
Amount due: 100.00
Lucy
23 Main Street
Roosky
Roscommon
Balance: 100
Discount: 10%
Amount due: 90.00
Fred
24 Main Street
Sneem
Kerry
Balance: 200
Discount: 0%
Amount due: 200.00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your class hierarchy, it is the `Discount` which should be overridable:

On base class `Customer`

```
    public class Customer
    {
        protected virtual float Discount => 0;
        ...
    }
```

On the valued customer subclass:

```
    public class ValuedCustomer : Customer
    {
        protected override float Discount => 0.1f;
        ...
    }
```

Now, in the `Owes()` method,

```
  return Math.Abs(balance * Discount - balance);
```

the polymorphic `Discount` will be retrieved, appropriate to the actual class instance type.

(Note I've updated variable names in accordance with .Net norms)

Comment: It's also true to say that the above is 'historic and academic' OO (3 Amigos) - as per Ignacio's answer, more modern SOLID principals would discourage using inheritance unnecessarily, especially if the subclass is just used to store a value.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you do not need two different classes and both have the same attributes but different values, pass the discount in the constructor or add a boolean to decide the discount to apply:

```
public Customer(string name, float balance, string addr1, string addr2, string addr3, float discount)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.addr1 = addr1;
    this.addr2 = addr2;
    this.addr3 = addr3;
    this.discount = discount;
} 

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Customer c1 = new Customer("Jimmy", 100, "22 Main Street", "Naas", "Kildare", 0);
        Customer c2 = new Customer ("Lucy", 100, "23 Main Street", "Roosky", "Roscommon", 10);
        Customer c3 = new Customer("Fred", 200, "24 Main Street", "Sneem", "Kerry", 0);

        Console.WriteLine(c1);
        Console.WriteLine(c2);
        Console.WriteLine(c3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, but my lecturer doesn't want the discount variable to be part of the constructor.

Comment: @webchatowner Tell your lecturer to hurry up with my french fries.